# Is $\int_0 ^1 \frac{1-x^p}{1-x} $ ever rational for rational non-integer values of $p$?

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, rational-numbers, hypergeometric-function, harmonic-numbers

It is well known that the $n$-th harmonic number $H_n$ has the integral representation $\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$. If we replace $n$ with rational non-integer $p$, do we ever get a rational outcome?

My only thought, due to W|A, is that $$\int\frac{1-x^p}{1-x}=-\frac{x^{p+1}}{p+1} {}_2F_1(1,p+1;p+2; x) - \log(1-x),$$ where $ {}_2F_1$ is the hypergeometric function, so what we're looking at is$$\lim_{x\to1^-}-\frac{1}{p+1} {}_2F_1(1,p+1; p+2; x)-\log(1-x).$$

Comment: The plot can be seen as shown here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=H_n
Wolfram Alpha does not state whether it is known or not that rational outputs exist for irrational inputs.

Comment: @JackLam: Note that I'm asking about rational outputs for rational non-integer inputs.

Comment: Going the same route as with harmonic numbers, and writing $p=n/m$, one can simplify to $n\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(km+n)}$ (assuming I did the math right). Likely unhelpful.

Comment: Probably not I would guess, atleast the first few values $p=1/2,1/3,2/3,1/4,3/4,1/5,2/5,\ldots$ looks irrational (result containing $\log$'s of integers and $\pi$'s). Proving this conjecture in general seems hard though.

Comment: @whacka: Thank you for reminding, it was helpful. :)

Comment: @Winther: Apart from the theorem mentioned in my answer, interestingly the authors also showed a counterexample to the conjecture would have implied the irrationality of the Euler-Mascheroni. So, a priori, I would say the conjecture was almost surely true. :v

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by whacka in the comments, the integral is equal to $$p\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+p)}=\gamma + \psi^{(0)}(1+p),$$ (where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant) which [was proved **transcendental** by M. Ram Murty and N. Saradha in 2007](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X06002927).

Note that in the link there is a typo, actually $1\le a\le q-1$, and that using $$ \psi^{(0)}\left(1+ \frac aq \right) = \psi^{(0)}\left(\frac aq\right) + \frac qa$$ we have transcendence for larger values of $a$ too (excluding multiples of $q$, of course).